# Rails passing variables from controller to a txt file and read using File.read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I am reading a txt file in ruby using File.read like below.

Let's say `@name = tom`

Text file contains.

```
Hello <%= @name %>
```

How can i pass @name to the text file and read it like below.

```
file = File.read('test.txt')
```

I want to pass rails instance variables to some places in txt file and read it so that **file** will be **Hello Tom** How can i achieve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? A text file is not a reasonable serialization format. I would get if you wanted to write JSON, YAML or XML but on this case it just seems like a pointless exercise.

Comment: Did you look into [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) ?

Comment: If you really want to do it though you need to parse the text either with a regular expression or by writing a real parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Render your text file from your controller (`send_file path_to_file`)
- Rename your text file to `my_original_filename.txt.erb`
- Adding the `erb` suffix tells Rails to process the Ruby in the text file first (Via ERB).